# C# call c++ method with string parameter from wrapped class

Tags: c#, c++, string

I am trying to call a method of a c++ class that uses a string parameter but I have this error

Error   CS0570  'Wrapper.write(int, ?)' is not supported by the language

Basically I have this code, and it works with other simple methods without string object

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799685/how-to-pass-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-from-c-to-c-using-dllimport) but as they are not static methods I can't use it

Any idea?

In C#

```
Wrapper tb = new Lib.Wrapper();
tb.write( 1, "tablas.txt");
```

In C++ Lib.h

```
private:
     myCppClass* pMyCppClass;
public:
     Wrapper();
     int write(int id, String^ file);
```

And C++ Lib.cpp

```
int Lib::Wrapper::write(int id, String^ file)
{
     std::string aux= marshal_as < std::string > (file);    
     return pMyCppClass->write(id, aux);
}
```

Comment: C++ lib is managed C++ ?

Comment: Yes, it is a manage c++  wrapping a unmaneged c++ class (myCppClass)

Comment: Can you give source C++ Lib?  I  tryed create it situation  but all work fine for manage C++.

Comment: I figured out the libraries wasn't updating so I delete the dll, clean the solution, recompile and add again the reference in C# and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the libraries wasn't updating so I delete the dll, clean the solution, recompile and add again the reference in C# and it works