# Returning a string from an unmanaged c++ dll to c#

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling

I'm trying to call unmanaged c++ from c# but receiving an exception about the return value.
The exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Arrays can only be marshaled as LPArray, ByValArray, or SafeArray).'

I have a similar function that look the same without the return value (void) that do work without any problems.

I set the platform (compiler) of the c++ project to be v100 (Visual Studio 2010) and use .net 4.5 at the c# project.

The c++ project created a lib+dll files that I put both at the executable folder.

When I try to replace the return value to be "String" at the c# code, the exception converted to be:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

When I remove the return value function property (`[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]`) I receive the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.'

And when I do the combination of: removing the return value function property and converting the return type to string, the application just close itself without catch any exception.

C++ code

```
extern "C"
{
    ExternalDll_API char* FuncA(char* projectId);
}

ExternalDll_API char* FuncA(char* projectId)
{
    return "abc";
}
```

C# code

```
[DllImport("ExternalDll.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern char[] FuncA(string projectId);

var key = FuncA(projectId.ToString());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799685/how-to-pass-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-from-c-to-c-using-dllimport

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, the proposed answer is based on 1-Knowing the size of the returned string, 2-Pass a StringBuilder and fill it from the C++ code, not returning directly a char pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To receive a null terminated string from a C++ dll you can do this:

1-Change the return type to `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("ExternalDll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FuncA(string projectId);
```

2-Retrieve the string from the pointer using Marshal:

```
var result = FuncA(someString);
var strResult = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);
```