# passed strings from C# is different with C++ strings , both are const char

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c# program that checks data base strings from a c++ dll.

I already read this pages :

- [How to pass strings from C# to C++ (and from C++ to C#) using DLLImport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799685/how-to-pass-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-from-c-to-c-using-dllimport)
- [Passing strings from C# to C++ DLL and back -- minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example)

My strings pass well with no error but my problem is **they're not matching in C++ dll.**

I tried to check them out with Messagebox , Console and Everything and they are same at characters , size , text ...

but **If Else** always returns false ...

My C++ code ( test_match.dll ) :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int check_string(const char* string_from_csharp);
int check_string(const char* string_from_csharp)
{
    if (string_from_csharp == "hello world!" ){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
}
```

My C# code :

```
[DllImport("test_match.dll",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl , 
CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int check_string(string string_from_csharp)
```

My C# code of usage ( WPF ) :

```
int get_match_state = check_string(inputtext.Text);
```

**MessageBox in C++ , says ... input is "hello world!"**

But it always returns 0

Also , I tried to convert them to wchar_t , std::string with find() but nothing changed.

**Where do I make a mistake?**
Thanks

Comment: You can not compare `const char*` with `==`.

Comment: I'm not a C++ programmer, but it looks like you're comparing *pointers* at the moment. If your parameter were a C++ `string` I'd expect `==` to behave in a more "content-based" way.

Comment: CharSet.Unicode is wrong, you need CharSet.Ansi to match a char* argument.  And you need to compare strings correctly, in the C language you use strcmp().  At least the CharSet mismatch should have been easy to discover with a debugger, be sure you know how to debug native code when pinvoked from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare strings like that :

```
if (string_from_csharp == "hello world!" )
```

If you absolutely need to use char*, use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), or [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int check_string(const char* string_from_csharp);
bool check_string(const char* string_from_csharp)
{
  return (strcmp(string_from_csharp, "hello world!") == 0);
}
```

You may want to use `std::string` since you're in C++. In that case, you'd use [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

Comment: thanks , but unfortunately your code not works , it always returns 0 , if I enter "hello world!" it returns false , If I enter "anything else" it returns false ... did you test your code ? with c# ?

Comment: @SamuelHardson: did you change the CharSet as Hans Passant told you to do?

Comment: @PaulF yes I did , I marked this answer and I added another answer of  Hans Passant . thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer belongs to Martin Véronneau and Hans Passant ( @hans-passant @martin-véronneau )

> CharSet.Unicode is wrong, you need CharSet.Ansi to match a char*
>   argument. And you need to compare strings correctly, in the C language
>   you use strcmp(). At least the CharSet mismatch should have been easy
>   to discover with a debugger, be sure you know how to debug native code
>   when pinvoked from C#. – Hans Passant

Thank you Hans and Martin!
The problem was `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`, I changed to `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` and now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As  tkausl and Daisy have mentioned in the comments I believe in C++ you are comparing pointer values instead of the actual string value. In your case I think the easiest way to do the comparison would be to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare the 2 strings.