# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt on DLL Import in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I have a C++ developed DLL which I want to load and call a function on C# but I got `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` Error. My C++ code is like below:

```
#include "EvenOdd.h"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) std::string CheckEvenOdd(const int iNum)
    {
        std::string strRes = "NULL";
        if(iNum%2 == 0)
        {
            strRes = "The given number is Even";
        }
        else
        {
            strRes = "The given number is Odd";
        }

        return strRes;
    }
}
```

My C# code is like Bellow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace C_Sharp_DLL_Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\saja\\Downloads\\LoadLibrary\\GetEvenOdd\\Debug\\GetEvenOdd.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
        static extern string CheckEvenOdd(int num);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = CheckEvenOdd(23);
            Console.WriteLine(s);   
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

That error occurs on `string s = CheckEvenOdd(23);` line. I test this code in Windows 10, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio 2010, and the debug profile on Visual Studio is on X86 CPU. [This is DLL download link.](https://gofile.io/d/ltghrW) [image: This is Error Screenshot download link.]

Comment: I've serious concerns that `std::string` (C++) is compatible to `string` (C#).

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to pass strings from C# to C++ (and from C++ to C#) using DLLImport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10799685/7478597)

Comment: You can't handle `std::string` (or `str::vector`, or `std::**anything**`) from C#, fullstop. Pass around C types.

Comment: I try to call a function that takes no argument but still the same error.

Comment: I tried StringBuilder and Char* but still the same error.

Comment: @xanatos Check top comments plz

Comment: @HojatSajadinia Scheff has serious concerns. I have certainty about the argument. And in general you can't pass out something that is on the stack C++-side. Your std::string is on the stack at it will be freed before returning to C#. There is no copy-constructor between C# and C++

Comment: You certainly cannot use `std::string` in pinvoke. Some research will give you the possibilities open to you. Naturally this is a topic that has been considered before. A great number of times.

Comment: If needed, I have a [github](https://github.com/xanatos/CSharpCPlusPlusInteropSamples) of examples of passing strings, structs and arrays between C/C++ and C#

Comment: You could consider using c++/cli rather than pinvoke. It might be simpler to do the type conversions yourself.